# Should the "auto-generate" tag be kept?

Tags: discussion, tags

The `auto-generate` tag does not seem particularly useful to me, it is not a technology name and is used for very various meanings of "generation":

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/auto-generate

Should it be deleted? (162 questions)

If the original goal was to talk about the GNU autogen tool, I suggest using "autogen" as a tag.